# Finding image and kernel of this set

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider $\mathbb{R_4}[x]$ the space of polynomial functions with degree less or equal than 4. Consider the linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R_4}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{R_4}[x]$ defined as $T(p(x)) = p(x+1) - p(x)$. Calculate $N(T)$ and $I(T)$

I have absolutely no idea how can I start this resolution... 
My professor said to us to not use matricial representation so please do not suggest that (I know it becomes easier)... Anyway, can someone give an hit to start the problem or just what I need to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at what happens to the basis polynomials $1,X,...,X^4$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kernel :

$p(x+1)=p(x)$ implies that your function is periodic with period 1. This is only true of constant polynomials, so the kernel is $\mathbb R_0[X]$

Image :

Consider the image of each basis element :

$$T(X^n)=(n-1)X^{n-1}+Q(X)$$
for $n\neq 0$ and with $Q$ a polynomial of degree $<n-1$. This means that $\deg (T(X^n))=n-1$. Therefore, the image of the basis is a family of polynomials of distinct orders 3,2,1,0. They generate $\mathbb R_3[X]$.

TL;DR : Ker = $\mathbb R_0[X]$, Im = $\mathbb R_3[X]$

Comment: I'm totally fine with the Kernel explanation, but didn't understand the Image explanation, can you please clarify this part... How are you calculating that expression for the image?

Comment: If you do the calculus you'll see $T(X^4)=3X^3+6X^2+4X+1$ for instance (I just didn't write down the entire calculation but I encourage you to do so if you're not comfortable with this). The important thing is that $T(\{X^4,X^3,X^2,X\})$ is a family of polynomials in $\mathbb R_3[X]$ with strictly increasing degree. This means that they are linearly independent. Since there are 4 (the dimension of $\mathbb R_3[X]$), they form a basis of $\mathbb R_3[X]$.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly the line
$$p(x+1) - p(x)$$
Can only be $0$ if $p(x+1) = p(x)$. Every polynomial is a well defined function, meaning it is continuous everywhere, but what set of functions easily answer this?

**Hint**
$$a_4(x - 1)^4 + a_3(x - 1)^3 + a_2(x - 1)^2 + a_1(x - 1) + a_0  - b_4x^4 + b_3x^3 + b_2x^2 + b_1x + b_0 = 0$$

What conditions need to be met? It seems that there's only a single polynomial basis. Now for imagespace, does the transformation actually change the degree of the polynomial?

**Note**: Set of all constants functions?
**Note**: The imagespace is also the set of all polynomials with degree less than 4.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to develop your expression to react to an expression with $x^4$, $x^3$... Now what can I conclude with the coefficients... Do I equal them to something?